# Size of integers in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

The book I have in front of me says that integers have a minimum width of 32.  Do you expect the width of integer to change from 32 bits to 64 bits, if I run my simulation tool in 64bit mode?  Or would you expect to be consistent between 32 and 64 modes of operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 1800-2012 LRM specifies that `integer`s (as well as `int`) are exactly 32-bits. I believe that any tool that supports Verilog and SystemVerilog will fix the size at 32 bits. As a hardware description language, the results must be independent of the tool implementation. Earliest versions of the Verilog standard did not have this requirement.